# In python, how can we make Saturday and Sunday come in the same week number

Tags: python, datetime

Let say June 01, 2020 starts with Monday and of the week number 22, June 6, is saturday of the same week number 22. Jun 7th is sunday and of the week number 23. I need June 6th and June 7th to be in the same week number either 22 or 23. How can I make it possible?

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. When working with `ISO calendar weeks`, every week starts with a Monday and ends (including) with a Sunday. The dates you mentioned are all week 23.

Comment: to clarify: you want the week to start on Monday? if so, see the answer provided by AKX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [ISO calendar weekdays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). In the ISO calendar, the dates you mention are all in the same week, 23.

```py
>>> datetime.date(2020, 6, 1).isocalendar()
# year, weekno, weekday
(2020, 23, 1)
>>> datetime.date(2020, 6, 6).isocalendar()
(2020, 23, 6)
>>> datetime.date(2020, 6, 7).isocalendar()
(2020, 23, 7)
>>>
```